# On Sampling rank $r$ matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra

Sample $n^2$ integers $a_{11},\dots,a_{nn}$ in $\{-d,\dots,-1,0,1\dots,d\}$ uniformly.

What is the probability that the resulting matrix $[a_{ij}]$ has rank $r$?

Is there a nice parametrization of such matrices that helps us generate such a rank $r$ matrix quickly deterministically?

In general what is a good strategy?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for $d\neq 0$.

Comment: The parametrization is the [Grassmanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian)

Comment: @BloodPudding that is true but that does not help getting away to sample deterministically.

Comment: @BloodPudding that should help in probability calculation though right?

Comment: that I don't know

Comment: What do you mean by "sample $n^2$ integers in $0\subsetneq[-d,d]$"? Is there a typo in your notation? It doesn't seem well-formed even syntactically, because $0$ is not a subset.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I tried to eradicate BloodPuddings degenerate condition

Comment: $[-d,d]\not\subseteq[0,0]$ does not look like well-formed notation either, to me, and I still don't understand what you mean by it.

Comment: I think he means choose $a_{1,1},a_{1,2},\ldots,a_{n,n}$ uniformly from {$-d,\ldots,-1$}$\cup${$1,\ldots,d$} but then he talks about deterministic sampling in the comments, which is puzzling.

Comment: no oh boy I will make it clearer

Comment: @kodlu I think it is pretty clear what is being asked. Q1: given $n^2$ integer of absolute value smaller than $d$, what are the odds that the matrix they generate has rank $r$? And Q2, what is an efficient algorithm for uniformly sampling from the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries < $d$ and rank $r$? Deterministic only means that the algorithm should not be probabilistic in the sense of giving the right answer only with probability $> 1 - \epsilon$ for a priori choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @ViditNanda that is correct interpretation (a parametrization would solve deterministically but may be some other cleverer way as well (which should technically be called paremeterization as well if it works deterministically))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case $r=n$ is considered in this [paper](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AAIMHNIE.pdf) by Martin and Wong.  They prove that for every $n \geq 2$ and every $\epsilon >0$, the probability that a random $n \times n$ matrix with entries from $\{-k, \dots, 0, \dots, k\}$ is singular is $\ll \frac{1}{k^{2-\epsilon}}$. See Lemma $1$.  The discussion following Lemma $1$ shows that this is tight for $n=2$, but not for $n >2$.  By a deep theorem of Katznelson, the true probability decays as $\frac{\log (k)}{k^n}$, which is not far from $\frac{1}{k^n}$ (the probability that a random matrix contains a row of zeros).

Comment: Singular means rank < n, not rank = 0.  What definition of rank are you using which even allows rank = 0?

Comment: nice. but you're allowing 0 as an entry which the OP didn't want.

Comment: In the latest edit the OP does allow zero as an entry.

Comment: I have always allowed 0 (notations were quite messy)